# Java Regex To Match List Of KeyWords- Non Greedy

Tags: java, regex

I have a working Java Regex except, given my logic, it is greedy.

The intention is to match only the 4 words including the keyword and not the spaces or words or characters before or after.

Sample Text:

```
  Chief Complaint
     Â· "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.."
     Â· "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.."  
    History of Present Illness
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting

    Review of Systems

    Donec luctus metus: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Donec luctus metus: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

    Past Medical History
     Â· Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text
     Â· Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text

    Social History
     Â· "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.."
     Â· "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.."

    Surgical History
     Â· "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.."

    Family History
     Â· "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.."

    Current Meds
     Â· "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.."
```

My Regex:

```
^[\s]*(?:\b(?:[Ss]ubjective|[Oo]bjective|[Aa]llergy|[Ll]aboratory|[Ll]ab|[Aa]llergie|[Ii]mpression|[Pp]lan|[Hh]istory|[Mm]ed|[Ee]xam|[Vv]ital|[Aa]ssessment|[Pp]roblem|[Cc]omplaint|[Ii]llness|[Ss]ystems|List|[Cc]hief|of|[Cc]urrent|[Pp]resent|[Ii]llness|[Pp]ast|[Mm]edica|[A-Za-z]|Comment:)+s?\b[\s]*){1,4}$
```

Online Tester Link:

http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/regex/85b4429f-59ed-4a0c-b016-f7a6ddce5344

Can you please suggest the edit ?

Comment: Could you put an example of correct output?

Comment: Yes. That is something I am not worried about. Because I will eventually pass the keywords from a list.

Comment: what do you mean by 4 words?

Comment: @albertoiNET : The correct output will the same keywords that the regex identifies but without leading white spaces. Correct - 'Current Meds', Incorrect - '                     Current Meds'

Comment: @ergonaut : "This is Right History" or "My history class" is what we want to capture for the keyword History but not "I am a random mention of word History somewhere in the sentence"

Comment: which quantifier is the problem?

Comment: @MaxZoom : The leading white spaces. ^[\s]* matches white spaces starting from preceding blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your text is formatted consistently.  Why don't you just do this?

```
^\s{7,8}([^ ].*)$
```

Which captures anything that only have 7 or at most 8 leading spaces.

Comment: I am scared this might not work out. Because the real text might not follow the same number of whitespaces through out

Comment: But it looks like you are matching Titles.  What if the keywords are inside the paragraphs?

Comment: Then we will be ignoring them. They fall out of the context.

Comment: Look at http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/regex/17689764-81a9-4f2a-a986-9710359b5020  You are matching aaaa as well.  So really your key words are useless.  What you're really looking to do is http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/regex/86faf37c-f0be-4988-8459-b2c6d1b853bf and replace all matches with a carriage return.

Comment: I see that's because of [A-Za-z] in the list of words.

Comment: yes, that's my point.  your question is unclear as to what you really want.